# Using for loop to generate values for each individual

Tags: r, for-loop

I am creating a for loop to obtain thermal minima and thermal maxima values for different individuals. At the moment, the output given for each individual is the mean for the population, rather than individual values for each individual. I assume that this is some issue with `data= ID_list[i]`

```
ID_list <- unique(temps$ID)

for (i in seq_along(ID_list)){model<- drm(Cumulative_Dist~Temperature, data= ID_list[i], fct=LL.4(names = c("Slope", "Lower Limit", "Upper Limit", "ED50")))
  summary(model)
  M1<-ED(model, c(10,90), interval="delta")}
```

How should I correct the code such that I obtain different values for each individual?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, it is not clear what you intend to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Is `ID_list` a list of Dataframes, with a dataframe for each individual?

Could it be that `temps` is a dataframe with ID and temperature: you can split those into a list by the following command:

```
# split the dataframe temps by the values found in temps$ID
# returns a list of dataframes
ID_list <- split(temps, temps$ID)
```

you can then acces the individual frame:

```
ID_list[[1]]

#or within the loop
ID_list[[i]]
```

The double `[` means tha R will return the list element and not a List with one element. Sometimes this causes problems.

Comment: Excellent! This solved the problem, thank you!